# What is wrong with my L7805CV + BUF 654 NPN transistor circuit

Tags: voltage-regulator

I really can't understand why this circuit get so **hot** and it does *not* turn on my LED strip (2 x 3 RGB leds).

I use a L7805CV voltage regulator, a BUF 654 NPN transistor. I have check the regulator and it works fine when it's not connected to the transistor, but I get strange low readings when I hook it up to the transistor. Taking out the 5V wire and connecting it again blinks the LED strip shortly.

[image: Circuit]

[image: LED strip]
Black wire: 12V
Red, Blue & green wires: color led GND
[image: Power supply]

[image]

### UPDATE

A lot have requested the schematics
[image: schematics]

I'm new at hobby electronics and don't find schematics that helpful - yet.
The LED strip has a lot of build in resistors.

I will use a ATtiny85 (arduino mini chip) to turn on the transistor - it has 5 V in and outputs - so will supply it with 5V from the L7805 and do some logic turn on (via the transistor) and PWM on the LED strip.

Comment: Could you draw a proper circuit diagram? Edit your question, hit Ctrl-M. Are you sure there are no resistors used in your circuit!? How much current does your LED strip draw?

Comment: Uh... what is this circuit of your supposed to do in the first place? That's kind of relevant information.

Comment: You are aware that (in reference to the bottom diagram) the pinout of the 7805 is IN, GND, OUT, and that the pinout of the NPN is B, C, E?  Your LED strip has a mysterious connection to the IN of the regulator; i.e. to the unregulated voltage.

Comment: Norfeldt: At the very least, Fritzing, which you have used for the breadboard diagram, also has the schematic view that you can switch to and rearrange components on. You can pretty up the components and connections in that schematic view, and then insert *that* into your question. A schematic is much more easily understood at a glance, than a breadboard diagram, so you would get help more quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You said:**

> I have check the regulator and it works fine when it's not connected to the transistor, but I get strange low readings when I hook it up to the transistor. Taking out the 5V wire and connecting it again blinks the LED strip shortly.

This is a sign that you are overloading your regulator. 7805 regulators have built-in thermal protection, which means that as they are getting hotter, their voltage sags and eventually refuses to operate. When you remove the power supply, the regulator cools just enough so that when you plug it in again, it turns on momentarily.

**More troubleshooting questions:**
Is your circuit hooked up right? You currently have the 7805 turning on the transistor, which then allows current to pass from the 12-volts into the LED strip and to ground. What's the point of having the 7805 regulator then?

**Also, the reason why the 7805 is getting too hot!**
The 7805 is connected to the base of the transistor, while the emitter is connected to ground. the base-emitter junction of the transistor acts like a diode.
[image]
If you want to do this you must have a *current limiting resistor*. Without it, your circuit essentially shorts the output of the 7805 regulator to the ground.

I would simply recommend removing the transistor altogether. The 7805 is rated for 1 amp, already more than what the 12-volt input can handle, which is 500mA, so you really don't need the transformer to boost the output. That should do the trick.

Personally, If I were to do this *particular* project, I would use an alternative voltage-drop solution. I would connect multiple diodes in series. Each diode drops the voltage by 0.6 volts. This prevents unwanted "waste" heat caused by the regulator, and would be much simpler to implement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Will try to answer some of your points by comments.

Comment: It's a debuggin process. I will have the 7805 Reg to supply power an AVR which will do some logic 5V on the transistor.

Comment: A random resistor did the trick :) Does it matter what size and watt the resistor is and can take ___?

Comment: The diodes are in series on the strip. They become warm (~40C) but also give a lot of light :D